# Set a constant of string in Dozer using custom converter

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

I was looking for a solution to set a constant value in Dozer mappings and have read a lot of answers concerning this question at stackoverflow. So I've decided to use a dozer custom converter.

Let me clarify my situation.

I have two beans with the following fields:

**Bean A:**

```
String name;

String phone;

String bankId;
```

**Bean B:**

```
String branch;

String phone;

String name;

String bankId;
```

The `branch` field of `Bean B` should be always equals to `"1111"`.

So I've created a custom converter:

```
public class ConstantToTypeConverter extends DozerConverter<String, String> {

    public ConstantToTypeConverter() {
        super(String.class, String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertTo(String source, String destination) {
        if (getParameter().equalsIgnoreCase("TYPE")) {
            return "1111";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertFrom(String source, String destination) {
        return convertTo(source, destination);
    }
}
```

And the following mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
          http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
    <mapping type="one-way" map-id="map-test">
        <class-a>BeanA</class-a>
        <class-b>BeanB</class-b>
        <field custom-converter="ConstantToTypeConverter"
               custom-converter-param="TYPE">
            <!-- Can use any existing field of String here, since there is a custom converter -->
            <a>name</a>
            <b>branch</b>
        </field>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

It works great and sets the `branch` value to `"1111"`. But this approach looks awful:

```
<!-- Can use any existing field of String here, since there is a custom converter -->
                <a>name</a>
                <b>branch</b>
```

I had to set a `name` field as a source in XML mapping just to initiate my custom converter, since Dozer requires both source and destination fields even if the source field doesn't actually needed. Generally, it makes my code unclear and hard to maintain.

I guess I did a mistake or used this approach in an inappropriate way. Can somebody please shed any light on this issue?

I use Dozer 5.5.1

Comment: If the value of branch should always be 1111, why not have the field initialized to that value in the Bean B class? I suspect your use case is more involved than what is presented here. Could you expand on the problem a bit so we can find a more meaningful solution?

Comment: Hi @JohnCamerin, thanks for the reply, you've caught my idea, assigning the value to "1111" at the constructor is obviously the best way. But `Bean A` and `Bean B` classes are from the third-party library and I can't change them. Of course, it's possible to set the value manually using a setter method, but my goal was to consolidate all mapping-related work under Dozer. My use case is actually more complex, but it only affects the quantity of fields in the beans and doesn't change the main idea.

Comment: I've done stuff like this before and made my CustomConverter a little more general and reusable by making the parameter be the value I want to set on the destination field. You still have the ability to use it against any pair of fields, but at least its a reusable custom converter in case you have another scenario like this.

Comment: @JohnCamerin Thanks for the tip, it will be useful in my case since I have a lot of such fields.

Answer (score 1):

Another option besides CustomConverter is creating a `BeanFactory` that initializes the bean.

```
public class BeanBFactory implements org.dozer.BeanFactory {
    @Override
    public Object createBean(Object source, Class<?> sourceClass, String targetBeanId) {
        return new BeanB(Constants.X, Constants.Y, ...);
    }
}

<mapping>
    <class-a>BeanA</class-a>
    <class-b bean-factory="BeanBFactory">
        BeanB
    </class-b>
</mapping>
```

You shouldn't count lines of code; it might be longer than hardcoding the conversion (at least for simple beans).